# how to use password field in serializers.py ..password2=serializers.Charfield(serializers.widget=PasswordInput()) doesnot work as it use

Tags: python, django, rest, anaconda, atom-editor

AttributeError: module 'rest_framework.serializers' has no attribute 'PasswordInput'

serializer.py :

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password2 = serializers.CharField(widget=serializers.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password']
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is self-explanatory. Your code should look like this.

```
password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
```

Read this StackOverflow post to answer your question in more depth
[how to mention password field in serializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189484/how-to-mention-password-field-in-serializer)