# Django Admin Password field displays plain text

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I extended the AbstractUser class, and then added a password2 field for password validation. However, in my admin page, my password2 field displays as plain text, instead of a hashed value just like the AbstractUser password field. I'd want my password2 value to be hashed as well.  How can that be done, please.

User Model:

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    profile_image = models.FileField(upload_to="profile_img")
    password2 = models.CharField(max_length=350, default="")
```

SignUp serializer:

```
class SignUpSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'password2', 'email',)
``
```

Comment: you need to call **`.set_password()`** method in the serializer class

Comment: Okay. With ```.set_password() ```, do I need to do a manual hashing?

Comment: No, `set_password()` will handle the hashing procedures

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to mention password field in serializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189484/how-to-mention-password-field-in-serializer)

Comment: It should. Thank you.