# How to allow blank password via django-rest-api user create

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, passwords, django-rest-auth, django-custom-user

In my case, I need to have one user group which email and password will not be set on user creation. They will not require to auth themselves either.

I managed to do custom user with a nullable email, but I cannot find a way to allow blank password in API call or Django admin forms. I do not really care much about forms, but I need to have it working via API.

How could I allow to create a new custom user with a blank password and maybe set it to something meaningful if it comes blank (like set_unusable_password())?

Thanks!

My `CustomUserManager`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        # if password == "":
        #     user.set_password(None)
        # else:
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can base your CustomUser on `AbstractUser` and use `set_password`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
...
```

Thanks to that, you have access to the function `set_password`. Any user based on CustomUser will inherit :

```
def set_password(self, raw_password):
    self.password = make_password(raw_password)
    self._password = raw_password
```

And if you look closely `make_password` you will realize it possible to give it `None` :

```
 if password is None:
    return UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_PREFIX + get_random_string(UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_SUFFIX_LENGTH)
```

You could check the [full example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) on Django to have a starting point with a `Manager`

Your model will look like :

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth']
```

UPDATE after you upload your Manager :

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(...
```

You forgot the `password=None` in your create_user. That is why you have this error required.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that I need `raw_password` `CharField` in my `CustomUser` which I set to `set_password()`? Is it ok to pass the password like this?

Comment: No. That's the point of the inheritance of AbstractBaseUser.

Comment: Ok, then I really do not understand your answer. I have added my custom user manager example. The problem is that I get `"password": ["This field is required."]`, so I cannot even attempt to set empty string I get to the set_password(). I had to use a custom field for email because of this reason, which sets `""` to `None`.

Comment: I updated. You made a small mistake in your Manager.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:
[how to mention password field in serializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189484/how-to-mention-password-field-in-serializer)

I have declared password field in user serializer and set `required=False`

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password = serializers.CharField(
        write_only=True,
        required=False,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("id", "email", "password")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['password'] = make_password(validated_data.get('password'))
        user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        Token.objects.create(user=user)

        return user
```